# Show messages as conversation separated by subject

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and I am trying to show messages as conversation and group by subject.

The current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE to='bob' ORDER BY date DESC

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $id = $row["id"] ;
        $from = $row["from"] ;
        $subject = $row["subject"] ;
        $message=$row["message"];
        $date=$row["date"];

<?php echo $subject;?>
<?php echo $message;?>
<?php echo $from;?>
<?php echo $date;?>
```

}

table "contact"

```
id | from | to  | subject  | message    | date
1  | Mike | Bob |  Soccer  |   Hi!      | 2016-08-15 06:43:35
2  | Mike | Bob |  Soccer  | How r u?   | 2016-08-15 06:45:00
3  | Mike | Bob |  Soccer  | Lets play! | 2016-08-15 06:46:10
4  | Mike | Bob |  School  | How was..  | 2016-08-16 08:40:00
```

This shows me:

Subject: Soccer

Hi! from Mike at 2016-08-15 06:43:35

Subject: Soccer

How r u? from Mike at 2016-08-15 06:45:00

Try GROUP BY subject but it shows only one result.

```
SELECT * FROM contact WHERE to='bob' GROUP BY subject ORDER BY date DESC
```

Appreciate any help in how to show messages group by subject.

Example:

Subject: Soccer

Hi! from Mike at 2016-08-15 06:43:35

How r u? from Mike at 2016-08-15 06:45:00

Lets play! from Mike at 2016-08-15 06:46:10

Subject: School

How was.. from Mike at 2016-08-16 08:40:00

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ build schema please and give us link.

Comment: The problem apparently is in your `php` code which you didn't provide...

Comment: A column called `idAccount` does not exist on that table

Comment: Corrected!  Thank you RiggsFolly.

Comment: We dont know what you actually want the result to be?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat (`group_concat`)

Comment: ...or do you want all the columns, not just all the messages of a thread?

Comment: Also show us you PHP script

Comment: if a have a conversation betwen same users with the same subject, I just need to show the subject once and the messages below it. my code shows  messages separated even with same subject.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are after, but you are not being completely clear about the results you want

```
SELECT * 
FROM contact 
WHERE to='bob' 
ORDER BY subject, date
```

Then your code can be changed like this to only print the category when it changes

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $last_subject = NULL;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        if ( $last_subject !== $row["subject"] ) {
            echo $row["subject"];
            $last_subject = $row["subject"];
        }

        echo $row["message"];
        echo $row["from"];
        echo $row["date"];
    }
}
```

Comment: With the Query, just amend your code accordingly to only print the category when it changes